# DXA Java 1.7 / 2.0 CTP: Broken images with special characters in file name

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-1.7, dxa-2.0

I see this question already being discussed and answered in the community also refering to this known and fixed issue: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/issues/32

However we are currently running DXA 1.7 (Java) and also 2.0 CTP (Java) and are still experiencing this exact same special characters issue.

On this screenshot you can see two images, the first is with `&` in file name, the second is not:
[image]

The web application is the DXA 2.0 CTP Example `ROOT.war` directly from the installation package without modifications. We have the same issue with our own modified webapp too.

Our developers are discussing if they should add their own `Servlet Filter` to fix this issue but i hoped this issue would be fixed by now and i am just missing some part, maybe in CMS config.

Could you give some clarification on this issue please?

Some additional logs if that helps:

```
DEBUG c.s.odata.client.DefaultODataClient - Getting entity for query ODataClientQuery[GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http://dxa20.example/en/images/T&I')]
DEBUG c.s.o.c.caller.BasicEndpointCaller - Preparing the call endpoint for given url: http://172.19.3.2:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http://dxa20.example/en/images/T&I')
DEBUG c.s.o.c.caller.BasicEndpointCaller - Request ended with 200 status code.
DEBUG c.s.w.c.i.i.StaticContentInterceptor - Handling static content: /en/images/T&I Bild ohne Ãœberschrift_tcm1209-372341_w1024_n.png
DEBUG c.s.w.a.d.DynamicMetaRetrieverImpl - Searching for binaryMeta for url='http://dxa20.example/en/images/T&I%20Bild%20ohne%20%C3%9Cberschrift_tcm1209-372341.png'.
DEBUG c.s.web.content.client.ContentClient - ForwardedClaims is configured. Will forward following claims: [taf:session:preview:preview_session]
DEBUG c.s.odata.client.DefaultODataClient - Getting entity for query ODataClientQuery[GetDynamicMetaFunctionImport(Url='http%253A%252F%252Fdxa20.example%252Fen%252Fimages%252FT%2526I%252520Bild%252520ohne%252520%2525C3%25259Cberschrift_tcm1209-372341.png',ItemType='BinaryMeta')]
DEBUG c.s.o.c.caller.BasicEndpointCaller - Preparing the call endpoint for given url: http://172.19.3.2:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetDynamicMetaFunctionImport(Url='http%253A%252F%252Fdxa20.example%252Fen%252Fimages%252FT%2526I%252520Bild%252520ohne%252520%2525C3%25259Cberschrift_tcm1209-372341.png',ItemType='BinaryMeta')
DEBUG c.s.o.c.caller.BasicEndpointCaller - Request ended with 200 status code.
DEBUG c.s.o.c.m.AtomEntityUnmarshaller - Unmarshalling entity for query: ODataClientQuery[GetDynamicMetaFunctionImport(Url='http%253A%252F%252Fdxa20.example%252Fen%252Fimages%252FT%2526I%252520Bild%252520ohne%252520%2525C3%25259Cberschrift_tcm1209-372341.png',ItemType='BinaryMeta')]
DEBUG c.s.w.a.d.DynamicMetaRetrieverImpl - Could not find Binary metadata by url: http://dxa20.example/en/images/T&I%20Bild%20ohne%20%C3%9Cberschrift_tcm1209-372341.png
DEBUG c.s.w.c.i.i.StaticContentInterceptor - Static resource not found in static content provider. Fallback to webapp content...
DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: It appears there was a change in Web 8.5 related to the support of .NET 4.5 (vs. .NET 4.0 on 2013), which causes the .NET method Uri.EscapeDataString(urlString) to change behavior (see also https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-8D684619-4A50-412C-AA87-F80F1CEC79D7). Customer Support has the following information on this : https://gateway.sdl.com/communityknowledge?articleName=After-Web-8-upgrade-why-do-binary-URLs-with-some-special-characters-display-as-broken-links, I'm looking into the issue and if it is requiring a change in DXA or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got the solution for this big problem.

Apparently this is a bug in `content-common-8.5.0-1013.jar` included in the Web 8.5 installation package from SDL. The jar is included in the `Preview Service` and the `Session Enabled Content Service`. We received a patched `jar` file from SDL called `content-common-8.5.0-1013.jar`. We needed to replace the old version with the new one for both services and this resolved the issue for us.

I am pretty sure this fix will be included in a near future hotfix or service pack.

Comment: UPDATE from SDL: R&D has now released an official hot fix on the issue with ampersand:
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/tree/DXA_1.7_Hotfix_1
This means that you do not need my temporary fix in CIS any longer and can use the fix in DXA instead.